# If I squash and merge my feature branches is there still a benefit in rebasing?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Let's say I have a feature branch called `feat-123` that is 24 commits ahead of master and 10 commits behind.

Scenario 1

- I rebase this branch with `master` and resolve merge conflicts so it is now 24 commits ahead and 0 behind.
- I push this branch to GitHub, open a pull request then click `Squash and merge`.
- All the work is condensed to 1 commit and added to the commit history on `master`.

Scenario 2

- I do `git pull origin master` on `feat-123` and resolve the merge conflicts
- I push this branch to GitHub, open a pull request then click `Squash and merge`.
- All the work is condensed to 1 commit and added to the commit history on `master`.

In the scenarios above, in both instances I ended up with 1 commit that contained all the work. Am I creating extra work for myself by rebasing or is there still a benefit?

Comment: In scenario 1, once you'd rebased you had the code reflecting what would be in master post-merge, so you could actually test what you'd end up with. In scenario 2 you didn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you please add this as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I creating extra work for myself by rebasing or is there still a benefit?

Depending on the amount and types of conflict: yes.

Whether you merge or rebase does not matter for the resulting state of the repository (assuming conflicts are resolved correctly and identically with both actions). The tip commits will contain all changes of your branch and the master branch in both scenarios.

If you run `git diff` between the rebased and merged branch, you shouldn't see any difference.

You can even try it out in your concrete repo:

```
git branch test-merge feat-123
git branch test-rebase feat-123
git checkout test-merge
git merge master
# resolve conflicts
git rebase master test-rebase
# resolve conflicts
git diff test-merge test-rebase
# you should not see any output
```